# Heroku Node App Builds successfully, but crashed

Tags: node.js, heroku

So, my node app gets uploaded to heroku and build goes fine but my app crashes and gives "internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:969" error. Claims I am missing a file, 'arrayParser', inside node_modules/pg-types/lib. And it is true I am. I check using heroku run bash. Locally everything runs fine. And locally the file 'arrayParser' is where it should be. I have another Heroku app that runs perfectly fine with the same node library installed. Was curious on what the issue could be here. Is Heroku not building my node_modules correctly or am I missing an something here.

Comment: which version of pg-types are you using? Have you tried removing your `nodes_modules` locally and re-building it from scratch?

Comment: This question isn't very clear. You're _describing_ what you are doing instead of _showing us_, and you're jumping all over. Please read [ask]. Including actual code snippets, error messages, etc. will help a _lot_.